# How to check if the file path is pointing to internal memory (or) sd card in android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard, android-storage

I have a file path to which I will be forming File obj and performing write operation. And I know that starting from Lollipop, you don't have write access to files in sd card and I have to request for sdcard root permission. My question is how do I know that that file path that I am using, is in sd card. I have read many blogs and many answers in stackoverflow, none of them have a clear answer. All I want to know is "I have a file path, is this file path pointing to internal memory or sdcard"

And how do I know if I have the write permission for the sdcard files ?

Comment: `And I know that starting from Lollipop, you don't have write access to files in sd card`. Indeed not with the File class or FileInputStream and so on but yes with Storage Access Framework you have full access to all files. So use that. If a classic file path starts with `storage/emulated/0/..` then it is in external memory of the device. If it starts with something like `/storage/1234-5678/..` then it is on a microSD card. In the classic way your app has no write permissions for microSD card exept for an app specific directory on it.

Comment: @blackapps, So can we say that any file which doesn't begin with storage/emulated/0/.. is on microSD card ?

Comment: That was a typo. I ment /storage/emulated/0/... No not any file. There are also private paths like /data/data/<packagename/ and relics from past like /sdcard or /mnt/sdcard. You should check for `/storage/####-####/..`pattern. But /mnt/sdcard2 could be the microSD card too.

Comment: @blackapps, Is there any solid pattern list for the sdcard file paths. Each manufacture have it in different way.

Comment: The all have /storage/####-####/.. now adays.